# iPhone 6 plus how to display more cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, iphone-6-plus

My `UITableView` displays the same amount of visible cells on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 plus.

How can I display more `UITableViewCell`s in an iPhone 6 since the screen is bigger. Shouldn't it display more cells automatically?

Comment: Have you added a iPhone 6 launch image? Otherwise your app will run in the old 4" resolution.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch perfect, thank! it works right now. but I still can imagine why Apple add this restriction, and why a media file affect on the behavior of device.

Comment: Apple made this opt-in because some apps might not be compatible with the higher resolution displays.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch yep, it make sense, but why for example don't use plist for this purposes with a key/value.

Comment: This thing is the same than when Apple launch iPHone 5 (568pt height). If you did't add a default-568h@2x.png the complete screen wasn't used. It's a way to say to Xcode than your App is ready for the new sizes.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch, I have added launch image and right now all my views that are on superview has extra space from the left and right some, but it worked good before. I mean before my views starts from 0 and has leading and trailing space equal zero as well, but right now it seems adds to some additional value to trailing an leading spaces. Did you have the same issue?

Comment: You have to fix those problems yourself, but this is exactly why the new resolutions are opt-in. Most apps don't adopt flawless to the new screens sizes.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch but I just started develop it from scratch. And seems iPhone 6 plus has some extra space from left and the right of a view. I use auto layout. and my view should scale form the left to the right corner to fill all screen horizontally, but right now there are an extra points form the left and right of view. Maybe you have faced with the same issue, and I should adjust auto layout.

Comment: In Xcode 6 some constraints involving some views (like a view controllers view) are set relative to the margins of the view by default, have you checked this? I'm not sure but maybe iphone 6 margins are wider than iphone 5 or 4.

Comment: I have added leading and trailing with control and mouse and as I checked it has -16, but the view starts from zero. If I using autolayout menu and uncheck constraints to margin it works good.